# Multiple level of Nested Dictionary using the unique values of each column as the Key for every level of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Given the list of dictionaries below, I am trying to create a multiple level of nested dictionaries using the unique values of each column (COUNTRY, PROCESS, QTR, MONTH) as the Key for every level.

```
[{'COUNTRY': 'USA',
  'PROCESS': 'Contributions',
  'QTR': '2018 Q1',
  'MONTH': 'March'},
 {'COUNTRY': 'USA',
  'PROCESS': 'Contributions',
  'QTR': '2018 Q1', 
  'MONTH': 'February'},
 {'COUNTRY': 'AP',
  'PROCESS': 'Communication',
  'QTR': '2018 Q4',
  'MONTH': 'October'},
 {'COUNTRY': 'AP',
  'PROCESS': 'Communication',
  'QTR': '2018 Q4',
  'MONTH': 'November'}]
```

I've tried using collections.defaultdict, but this only gives me the first level.

```
{'USA': [{'PROCESS': 'Contributions',
          'QTR': '2018 Q1',
          'MONTH': 'February'}]
```

This is the sample code that I use:

```
s = filters_ALL
d = defaultdict(list)

for row in s: #Format the results 
    d[row['COUNTRY']].append({
        'PROCESS': row['PROCESS'],
        'QTR': row['QTR'],
        'MONTH': row['MONTH']
        })
```

I expect an output similar to this:

```
COUNTRY: {
         'USA': {
                Process: {
                          'Contributions': {
                                            QTR: {
                                                  '2018 Q1'
                                                  '2018 Q4': {...}
                                                 }
                                           }
                         }
                },

         'AP': {
                Process: {
                          'Contributions'{...}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? This is pretty sloppy, but I think it gets you towards the next steps:

```
from pprint import pprint    

r = {}

for d in c:

  if d.get('COUNTRY') in r:

    x = r[d.get('COUNTRY')]

    if d.get('PROCESS') in x:

      x = x[d.get('PROCESS')]

      x.append(
        {
          'QTR': d.get('QTR'),
          'MONTH': d.get('MONTH')
        }
      )
    else:
      x[d.get('PROCESS')] = [
        {
          'QTR': d.get('QTR'),
          'MONTH': d.get('MONTH')
        }
      ]
  else:
    r[d.get('COUNTRY')] = {
      d.get('PROCESS'): [
        {
          'QTR': d.get('QTR'),
          'MONTH': d.get('MONTH')
        }
      ]
    }

pprint(r)
```

Output:

```
{'AP': {
   'Communication': [
          {'MONTH': 'October', 'QTR': '2018 Q4'},
          {'MONTH': 'November', 'QTR': '2018 Q4'}
        ]
 },
 'USA': {'Contributions': [
          {'MONTH': 'March', 'QTR': '2018 Q1'},
          {'MONTH': 'February', 'QTR': '2018 Q1'}
         ]
        }
}
```